# jQuery .clone() refreshes the page in safari

Tags: jquery

When I call

```
var newElement = $(someElement).clone();
```

It refreshes the page immediately in Safari. I use jQuery v1.6.4. and Safari v5.1. In Chrome and Firefox the above call works perfectly.

Here is the code that refreshes the page in safari.

```
function resetAllAudioPieces()
{
    var audioPieces = $(".audio-piece");
    audioPieces.each(function(index){
        var newElement = $(audioPieces[index]).clone();
        $(audioPieces[index]).replaceWith(newElement);
        $(audioPieces[index]).removeClass("playing");
        $(audioPieces[index]).disableSelection();
    });
    return;
}


$("a#stop").live('click', function(e){
   resetAllAudioPieces();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I click the "#stop" link, the page refreshes. Is this a bug in jQuery clone() ? Please help.

Comment: Do you really mean _refresh_, or just _redraw_?  The former normally implies refetching the content from the server.

Comment: Where do you set `$oldElement` and what's the contents?

Comment: Also, the page refresh is probably because there's a JS error and the normal click event isn't blocked. Try changing the event to `mouseover` so that you can see the JavaScript errors.

Comment: you don't need the extra $() wrapping in the replaceWith since newElement is already a jquery element at this point.

Comment: why does it happen only in safari when others work fine

Comment: even when I call `resetAllAudioPieces()` in console, the page refreshes in safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try without the "return;" and switch the preventDefault position ?

```
function resetAllAudioPieces()
{
    var audioPieces = $(".audio-piece");
    audioPieces.each(function(index){
        var newElement = $(audioPieces[index]).clone();
        $(audioPieces[index]).replaceWith(newElement);
        $(audioPieces[index]).removeClass("playing");
        $(audioPieces[index]).disableSelection();
    });
    // return;
}


$("a#stop").live('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   resetAllAudioPieces();
});
```